# knockou.js getting model from server mapping with mapping plugin and sending the model back

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I started using knockout.js and i really like it. 
I use ASP.Net mvc , jQuery and knockout.js

My question is this:
lets say i have a management screen of a user, the user is my view model 
inside the user i want an array of permissions

my user viewModel:

```
var userViewModelClass = function () {
   var self = this;
   ko.mapping.fromJS({
       ID: "",
       permissions: []
   }, {}, self);
}
```

now.. if i do an ajax request to the server and get a JSON back i user the mapping plugin, and everything goes as expected

but... now i want my rendered permissions list to have an action like delete.
so i will need a permission object and then the array of permissions will be an array of permission objects. but how do i do that? how will the mapping plugin know that the object returned to him from the server in an array is actually on object like this one:

```
 function permission() {
   var self = this;
   this.delete = function () {       
   };
   ko.mapping.fromJS({
       name: "",
       level: ""
    }, {}, self);
}
```

that's my first part of the question. 
the second part: 
lets say i got the model with an array of all permissions and they are all of this permission object. now i want each delete button in my view to be bind the the delete function inside the permission object.
using:

```
data-bind="click: delete"
```

what is the best implementation for a delete function? i thought about something like:   makeing an ajax call to the server which will actually delete the permission from the user. then if the call succeeds remove the current permission from the observable array, then the view will update... 
is that a good practice?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First part. You need to use mapping options. In your `userViewModelClass` do this.

```
var userViewModelClass = function () {
   var self = this;
   ko.mapping.fromJS({
       ID: "",
       permissions: []
   }, {
       permissions: {
           create: function(options) {
               return new permission(options.data);
           }
       }
   }, self);
}
```

And modify your permission object like so

```
function permission(config) {
   var self = this;
   this.delete = function () {       
   };
   ko.mapping.fromJS($.extend({
       name: "",
       level: ""
    }, config), {}, self);
}
```

Note I added the extend in so that your default structure will remain and be overwritten by incoming data.

Second part of your question. One possible way would be to pass a reference to the parent in your constructor. So the above mapping options would become

```
permissions: {
    create: function(options) {
        return new permission(options.data, self);
    }
}
```

Then your delete could be something like.

```
this.delete = function () {  
    $.ajax(deleteurl, yourdata, function(result) {
       // success
       parent.permissions.remove(self);
    }, function() {
       // failure
       display error message
    }     
};
```

**EDIT**

Alternate way as discussed in comments.

```
var userViewModelClass = function () {
   var self = this;
   ko.mapping.fromJS({
       ID: "",
       permissions: []
   }, {
       permissions: {
           create: function(options) {
               return new permission(options.data);
           }
       }
   }, self);

   this.delete = function(permission) {
       self.permissions.remove(permission);
   };
}

data-bind="click: $parent.delete"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you ill try it soon and get back here :) ,
i understand the first part and it look nice. but i didn't like the second part.. think about it you have an object containing an object, and that second object will have a refrence to its father?.. and then you have this line:  parent.permissions.remove(self); you go to the parent then to the collection you are in and then remove your self. seems weird for me.. i understand that it will work but its still weird. i think what its missing is events

Comment: I was just showing you a way to do it with plain js the way you had it laid out. In my opinion, delete should actually be a member of the parent not the child. So your delete method should be on the userViewModel class. Events are over complicating things in this trivial scenario.

Comment: thank you very much! didn't know about this: $parent.delete yup this certainly answer my question and also looks great. thanks